# ROS multi thread c++

Tags: ros, multi-thread

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I developed two separate program and tested them. One program is for socket communication with external network the other one is for internal ros work. But then I add the first program as thread into ROS package and run the program I get this error:

```
Error message is that "malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion '(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1)*2])) -
__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0)"
```

I couldn't find any solution on the internet.
Here is my source code and I omitted some not important parts.
By removing line by lime I localized that the cause of error is in this line "SocketAddress sa(IPAddress(), 50000);". The error though appear right at the beginning of the program so I can really debug it. I guess the error is related to stack memory.

please help me.

---

```
using namespace std;
using namespace Poco::XML;
using namespace Poco::Net;
namespace enc = sensor_msgs::image_encodings;
 
 
AutoPtr<Document> pDoc;
sensor_msgs::CameraInfo info_cam;
std::vector<cv::Point> platform_corners(NUMBER_OF_CORNERS);
image_transport::Publisher pub_cropped;

class HelloRunnable: public Poco::Runnable{
    virtual void run(){
            SocketAddress sa(IPAddress(), 50000);
                DatagramSocket sock(sa);
                           //other code
    }
};
}

int main (int argc, char** argv){
    int i = 0;
    HelloRunnable runnable;
        Poco::Thread thread;
        thread.start(runnable);
        thread.join();
    ros::init (argc, argv, "locateCamera");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    boost::shared_ptr<image_transport::ImageTransport> it_(boost::shared_ptr<image_transport::ImageTransport>(new image_transport::ImageTransport(nh)));

    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe ("/ar_pose_marker", 1, &getCornersInPixCB);
    ros::Subscriber sub_info_l = nh.subscribe("/camera/camera_info", 1, &getCamInfoCb);
    
    ros::spin ();
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191503/ros-multi-thread-c++/) by [pjnsoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/19994/pjnsoo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's likely that you're corrupting your memory. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987207/why-do-i-get-a-c-malloc-assertion-failure

When running standalone you may be getting luck that the memory being corupted is less critical. As linked I suggest you use valgrind and make a minimal example to isolate your problem.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0